# How can i access node_load () in my php page

Tags: 7

I created a PHP page within my project and I am using `node_load()` to print data.

I also used these includes in my php page:

```
include 'modules/node/node.module';
include 'includes/common.inc';
```

But I get an error about an undefined function, like so:

> Call to undefined function cache_get() in
>   D:\xampp-portable\htdocs\d6\includes\common.inc on line 3321"

So how can I access the 'node load' function in my page?

Comment: Function is not `noad_load()` but `node_load()`. Take a look at `node_load()` function at [Drupal API page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7).

Comment: i included it include 'modules/node/node.module';
      include 'includes/common.inc';  in my php page but error is comming "Call to undefined function cache_get() in D:\xampp-portable\htdocs\d6\includes\common.inc on line 3321"

Comment: What is the php file name?

Comment: I have no idea what you are up to...are you doing some theming or what? what your PHP file should do, what is the file's name, and where is it placed?